# btrfs on LVM on LUKS - one LUKS container performs WAY better than the other

Tags: performance, btrfs, luks, lvm

I have 2 LUKS containers, one with default OpenSUSE installer settings, another one with `-h sha512 -s 512 -i 5000` and detached header. On top of each of them there is LVM - one with only 1 OS volume which is btrfs, another one (detached) with 3 volumes - swap, ssd cache and btrfs data. The problem is that btrfs on OS volume perform A LOT better than data volume. The one with OS performs more or less like raw btrfs on LUKS without LVM, the one with data achieves like... 50MB/s sequential on Samsung SSD PRO... (It's slower than WD Green HDD) I've planned to use this volume for VMs but it's slow as hell, Win10 is booting like a minute or so, comparing to few seconds when on OS partition.

OS volume was created by OpenSUSE installer with default settings. The one with data was created manually with `mkfs.btrfs` without any flags except `label`. Here are mount parameters:

`/dev/mapper/linux-suse on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,discard,space_cache)`
`/dev/mapper/data-data on /home/lapsio/VMs type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache)`

First thing to blame would be ofc compression, but actually VMs dir has set `chattr -R +C VMs/` flag on it as well as on all files inside. I've also tried to defragment this dir but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you overwrite the data SSD with random data before creating the LUKS volume on it (as recommended—I think inappropriately—by some guides)? That could cause massive [write amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification) and worsen internal fragmentation on the SSD, which would slow I/O down.

Comment: nope, I didn't even delete partitions, just generated new partition table, then created 2 LUKS containers, then installed OpenSUSE on the first one (with creating LVM), then from running SUSE partitioner created second LVM on second LUKS and created manually btrfs on it. Also Samsung 850 PRO has lots of TBW and warranty so welp, I don't really care about TBW and it's just 256gb drive so hard to pump much data through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my... I didn't mention this drive was moved from laptop where as the only drive it was 99% filled up with data. First LVM is mounted automatically at OS startup and has enabled TRIM (I know it's not recommended on encrypted devices as it reveals data organization on disk but OS partition contains only OS, not actual important data), second LVM was mounted manually from command line and didn't have enabled TRIM (because well I'm not planning to use TRIM there anyway). But in matter of fact this 180gb partition (on 256gb drive) or rather data cells covering this part of drive weren't trimmed at all since it was mounted in PC.

After I've manually TRIMed this LUKS partition it works fine